# Difficulty uploading images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

I have installed the paperclip gem in order to be able to upload images on my page but anytime i try uploading the images it gives me these two  error  messages "Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError"
"Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be"

Comment: is your system has installed `ImageMagick`? and have you wrote the code for image field code in your model?

Comment: yes i have installed ImageMagick and i have inserted the Url into the development.rb file

Comment: can you update your question with mode details? like your model code for paperclip configuration.

Answer (score 0):

U Install imagemagik gem also

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: im using windows

Comment: i did that and i configured it but it gives me that error i put up